# What's the earliest use of man as a suffix?

Tags: etymology, history

In words such as *fireman* and *tribesman*, the suffix *-man* means "one having responsibility for" or "one belong to" (and possibly other types of relationship, such as the bewildering variety demonstrated by the genitive *'s*).

What's the earliest recorded use of the suffix *-man* with this or a similar meaning in English?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like "man"/"men" has always been used like this. For example, "shipmen" (meaning sailors) was used in [Bede's Ecclesiastical History](https://books.google.com/books?id=3xwRUr5t9ioC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200), which was written around the year 900:

> Þa ongunnon þa nedlingas & þa **scipmen** þa oncras upp teon.